# javax.websocket.DeploymentException

Tags: java, websocket

I am using Intellij IDEA.
And i am trying to coding java websocket.
But i have an error.
How can i fix this bug.?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NTLMException {
        runServer();
    }

    public static void runServer() throws NTLMException {
        Server s = new Server("localhost", 8000, "/ws", WsServer.class);
        try {
            s.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Please press a key to stop the server.");
            reader.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            s.stop();
        }


@ServerEndpoint("/websocket")
public class WsServer {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        logger.info("Connected.:" + session.getId());
    }



    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        switch (message) {
            case "quit":
                try {
                    session.close(new CloseReason(CloseCodes.NORMAL_CLOSURE, "END"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                break;
        }
        return message;
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
        logger.info(String.format("Session %s closed because of %s", session.getId(), closeReason));
    }
}
```

1. 

> > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> > > javax/websocket/DeploymentException     at
> > > ws.Main.runServer(Main.java:14)     at ws.Main.main(Main.java:10) Caused
> > > by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> > > javax.websocket.DeploymentException     at
> > > java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)  at
> > > java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)   at
> > > sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)   at
> > > java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)   ... 2 more

Comment: How are you building and running your program?

Comment: Hello. Firstly, Thanks for your comment. Normally, main method run this websocket in localhost, on 8000 port. Is not it.?